# Select rows where day is less than today

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I select rows in the past starting from yesterday in Oracle DB where a field like `created_date` is a `timestamp(6)`?

I don't want to compare time, just date.

Comment: Please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574565/oracle-how-can-i-select-records-only-from-yesterday

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm

Comment: Use INTERVAL literals

Comment: @saurabh I've read this before, and I didn't like the answer. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Thanks, @SurgeonofDeath. The example from the docs worked. Can you make a answer on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Oracle documentation on SELECT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm#i2105152) :

```
SELECT * FROM orders
  WHERE created_date < TO_DATE('2014-04-28', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

I can pass this date format from my application, worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

If you want exactly one day prior to the current time:

```
select *
from table t
where created_date < sysdate - 1;
```

If you want times before today:

```
select *
from table t
where created_date <= trunc(sysdate);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want to compare just date:

```
select *
from table t
where date(created_date) < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Comment: Minus 1 for not using oracle functions and for using a function on the created_date field in the where clause.  That slows down production.

Comment: @DanBracuk: Oracle supports `Function-based indexes`, and the questioner wants to compare just date.

and I see `DATE_SUB` here in Oracle documentation:  [http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub]

Answer (score 0):

you can use cast function to deal with timestamp as date:

```
SELECT cast(SYSTIMESTAMP(6) as date)
FROM   dual;
```

so you can select rows with "yesterdate" date by:

```
select ....
where cast(SYSTIMESTAMP(6) as date) like sysdate - 1
```

note: replace SYSTIMESTAMP(6) with column name which has timestamp type.