# oracle: query timestamp with variable dates

Tags: database, oracle, date-arithmetic

In all my scripts, I want to query Oracle to give me rows having a time stamp less than todays date (today's date at 12 am) and greater than the last day at (12 am)
I have already come up with the following scripts:

```
WHERE DAILY_OPEN_POSITIONS.OPEN_TIMESTAMP <= (SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP FROM DUAL) 
AND DAILY_OPEN_POSITIONS.OPEN_TIMESTAMP >= (SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '2' DAY FROM dual)
```

but this is not exactly what I want, because it gives rows not started at 12 am, but rather from current time.

I am looking for a way to mix variable date (every day date) and constant time (12 am) together so my queries will be limited to:

```
WHERE DAILY_OPEN_POSITIONS.OPEN_TIMESTAMP <= (today's date started at 12 am) 
AND DAILY_OPEN_POSITIONS.OPEN_TIMESTAMP >= (yesterday's date started at 12 am
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle: How can I select records ONLY from yesterday?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574565/oracle-how-can-i-select-records-only-from-yesterday)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need subqueries to access functions.  I think you just want `trunc()`:

```
WHERE DAILY_OPEN_POSITIONS.OPEN_TIMESTAMP <= trunc(SYSTIMESTAMP) AND 
      DAILY_OPEN_POSITIONS.OPEN_TIMESTAMP >= trunc(SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '2' DAY)
```

However, I think it should be '1' day in the second condition.

Comment: Yes right, it should be one day. But, what about the script runs at 00:01, then interval -1 will not point to the last day. that is the main question, can I explicitly say to execute queries at this date started at 00 and previous date started at 00

Comment: but that gives the results from yesterday at 12:01 am to current time. I want it to be from yesterday at 12:00 to today at 12:00.

Comment: @user1596226 . . . No, the `trunc()` removes the time component.